# How do we explain this new take on the old Twins Paradox?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

Here's a new take on the age old Twins Paradox that I have not been able to figure out.

We have two twins in two separate space ships at the same place and time. Twin A fires his thrusters for 1 year (proper time) of acceleration at 1 g, followed by 2 years of reverse acceleration at 1 g, followed by 1 year of acceleration at 1 g in the original direction, thus returning to his original position and inertial reference frame with twin B. During that time, Twin B went nowhere, but spent the time in a centrifuge, experiencing 1 g of acceleration, just like Twin A (albeit in different directions).

Both twins experienced 1 g of acceleration for 4 years (of Twin A's life), but analysis indicates that Twin B would have aged more than 4 years. Even if we treated the time in the centrifuge under 1 g as equivalent to 1 g of gravity on Earth, the gravitational time dilation is nowhere near the time dilation caused by Twin A's travel. Can someone explain where my analysis might be off?

Edit:

Just to clarify the paradox of this new scenario:
Both twins experience 1 g of acceleration for the entire interval.
Twin A experienced linear acceleration.
Twin B experienced centrifugal acceleration.
How does this only difference cause time-dilation between them?

Edit:

Sorry to have compared this scenario to the Twins Paradox, because that is not really what it is about. The answers to the Twins Paradox were accurate, but not the point.

Let's take 3 persons all staring at the same place and same time with no velocity with respect to each other. Person A experiences linear acceleration only. Person B experiences centrifugal acceleration only. Person C experiences gravitational acceleration only. There is no experiment that any of the 3 could do to determine the type of acceleration they are experiencing (in a black-box scenario). After an interval, they all return to the same position, each one having experienced the exact same magnitude (but not direction) of acceleration for the whole time. How is it that Person A experiences Lorentz time-dilation with respect to Person B, and Person C experiences gravitational time-dilation with respect to Person B? The appropriate analysis and formulas indicate that this is the case, but I would appreciate someone trying to explain the conceptual difference.

Comment: How did you specifically do this analysis. If there is something wrong this could help point out what it is.

Comment: All of the acceleration is at the same 1g, so both twins are equally affected by gravitational time dilation, so you can ignore that part.  Once you've ignored it, this is just the usual twin paradox, with the usual resolution.  This question should certainly be closed.

Comment: @WillO, can you elaborate on why the quesiton should be closed?  Just because a simple solution may exist, doesn't mean a question needs to be closed in my opinion

Comment: @kenshin:  If you're going to allow the question "How do you resolve the twin paradox when one twin sits in a centrifuge?" then you've also got to allow the question "How do you resolve the twin paradox when one twin wears a red hat?" or "How do you resolve the twin paradox when one twin is a mezzosoprano?", and for that matter "Is momentum still conserved  on holidays?"  There is no end to asking the same question over and over with some new  irrelevant hypothesis tacked on.  I don't think it's a good idea to allow such questions.

Comment: @WillO, I don't think this question is quite like those examples.  The question's misunderstanding was that it is the "acceleration" that breaks the symmetry in the twin paradox, and thus posits what happens if both twins undergo acceleration.  This is a perfectly logical question to ask, and happens to have a simple solution.

Comment: @kenshin:  Yes, but it's also perfectly logical to think that color of one's hat breaks the symmetry in the twin paradox.  The question is not whether it's logical, but whether it's a reasonable thing for the questioner to have thought about before posting.  There's room for disagreement about where to draw the dividing line, but to me it seems that a) a very small amount of noodling around with equations will dispose of this misconception, b) it's reasonable to expect the OP to have done that noodling around, and in any event  (CONTINUED),

Comment: (CONTINUED) c)  if you take a few minutes to read through any one of the six kajillion good explanations of the twin paradox that are already on this site, it's crystal clear that they're not going to change if you put a twin in a centrifuge.  I very much think that before asking a question like this, the OP should have read one of those answers, stuck in his centrifuge, and looked to see if it changed anything.

Comment: @WillO, I think the mathematics of special relativity within a centrifuge (which does enter into the equations) are are lot more complex than the mathematics of special relativity when wearing a red hat (which doesn't enter into the equations).

Comment: @Kenshin:  I think you are mistaken, actually. If I treat you as a point particle (as we always do in SR) then your worldline is exactly the same whether you spin or not, so  the spinning has exactly the same effect on the equations as a red hat would, i.e. no effect at all.

Comment: @WillO I think you are being pretty harsh here. The case of acceleration and the case of something like wearing a hat are not on the same conceptual footing. You could have just posted a great answer to this question based on what you are saying in your comments.

Comment: @WillO, I would suggest that this scenario is a new (related) paradox, not the same paradox with a new dressing. The standard twins paradox involves 1 twin experiencing acceleration and the other not. This scenario involves both twins experiencing the same acceleration, just in different directions.

Comment: @StuartVanHorne :  In many presentations of the Twin paradox, one twin is male (often named Bob) and the other is temale (often named Alice).  If I make both the twins male is that a new (related) paradox or the same paradox with a new dressing?

Comment: @WillO, certainly not. I'm actually changing the underlying cause of the time-dilation. acceleration --> velocity --> time-dilation

Comment: @StuartVanHorne:  The acceleration has exactly as much to do with the  time dilation as the twins' names do.  This is easiest to see if you eliminate the acceleration entirely by having Bob turn around in literally an instant, so he is outbound up to and including time $T$ and inbound thereafter.  Then  at every single instant along the journey, Bob and Alice see each other's clocks run slow by exactly the same amount.   The resolution of the "paradox" is that Bob, at some point, changes frames, not that he accelerates.   Spinning in a centrifuge changes only the spatial part of your frame.

Comment: @StuartVanHorne:  Sorry, this didn't quite fit in the last box.  Turning around in a can only change your frame by the action of an element of $SO(3)$ (imbedded in $SO(3,1)$ in the obvious way) and so can't contribute to special relativistic time dilation.

Comment: @WillO, so acceleration never causes time-dilation in and of itself (putting aside gravitational time-dilation), but it does cause a change of reference frames, which might cause time-dilation. And linear acceleration changes reference frames to cause time dilation, and centrifugal acceleration changes the reference frame but doesn't cause time-dilation. Is that close to what you're saying?

Comment: @stuartvanhorne:  all I am saying is that anyone who reads and digests any of the easily available posts resolving the twin paradox will see that spinning has as little to do with the resolution as the twins' names do, and that therefore this question should be treated just as we would treat a question that  put a "new twist" on the problem by changing their names.  That is 100% of what I am saying.

Comment: So I guess the question is, how does one form of acceleration create a constantly changing reduction of the rate of the passage of time (Linear), yet the other form of acceleration does not (Centrifugal).

Answer (score 2):

The traveling twin ages less, and the acceleration doesn't resolve the paradox. In the standard version, the paradox is resolved when the traveling twin (who's name is traditionally "B") turns around. This turn around can take $\epsilon \rightarrow 0\ $ seconds in the Earth frame, so it cannot account for "lost" time. The change in the definition of the hyper-plane of simultaneity at the turn around event resolves the paradox--so that each twin can observed the other's clock going slower for the duration of the journey (which is a paradox with or without different total aging).

Comment: That very change in the definition of simultaneity is caused by acceleration. And no matter how small $\epsilon$ can be made, the change in velocity $\Delta v$ is finite and fixed. So I agree with your explanation, but not with "acceleration doesn't resolve the paradox".

Answer (score 2):

The twin paradox is purely special relativity. You don't need the general relativity tag.

The twin paradox can be resolved without acceleration by using three or more observers.

[image]

The first one, A, sits at home with no acceleration. The second, B, starts out at t=0, x=0, right next to A, with speed v. The third, C, starts out at x=D, t=T, speed negative v as observed by A. C is arranged such that he passes B at the point we will call the "turn around."

So you've got a little triangle with three observers. It's possible to synchronize the clocks of B and C at the point they pass. Then you wait for C to return to A. Then you can compare the clock of A and C when they just pass.

Then by symmetry, the time B observes from being beside a to beside C has to be the same as the time C observes from being beside B to beside A.

Then you can have comparison of clocks only at the points two observers are at the same location. And you can do it with no acceleration. You don't have to worry about confusion over synchronizing clocks at a distance.

No acceleration. No synchronization except for clocks right beside each other. You will still get the Lorentz transform.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. To remove acceleration completely makes it a much simpler scenario and puts it completely in the realm of Special Relativity.

Comment: @StuartVanHorne I agree that GR isn't needed in the twin paradox but I don't think this scenario does anything to prove that. If the GR explanation were valid, it would still apply in the limit as $t \rightarrow 0$ and $a \rightarrow \infty$ at the turnaround (and note that $t$ could only ever approach $0$; it couldn't reach it because then there would be a discontinuity in the traveling twin's perception of his sibling's age). But there are other good arguments (including experimental evidence) that acceleration doesn't directly cause time dilation.